# Удаление строчки при клике на кнопку

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, у меня такой вопрос:
Есть input с таким кодом:

```
<input type="text" value="Javascript;css">
```

Как мне сделать, что бы при клике на кнопку, удалялась строчка Javascript; а css осталась?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С помощью [replace](http://javascript.ru/String/replace):

```js
var field = document.getElementById('field');
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    field.value = field.value.replace(/javascript;/i, '');
}, false);
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Javascript;css" id="field" />
<button id="btn">Тык</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s6T8f/1/