# Удаление текста в input

Tags: javascript

Я недавно задавал вопрос:
[Удаление строчки при клике на кнопку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/335245/javascript-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8)

Вот такая проблема:
Есть такой код

```
<input value="lalala;mememe" id="1">
```

И есть еще одни

```
<input value=";mememe" id="2">
```

Как мне сделать что бы строчка указанная в input id="2" удалялась из input id="1"

Comment: по тому же принципу, что и в первом вопросе. тыжпрограммист. подумай. и да, айди не должны начинаться с цифры.

Comment: ну ладно, подумаем

Comment: Удалять-то по какому событию хотите?

Comment: @mountpoint "айди не должны начинаться с цифры" - это не так для html5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удаляется по тому же принципу:

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
  var a1 = document.getElementById('a1'),
      a2 = document.getElementById('a2');
  var reg = new RegExp(a2.value, 'i');
  a1.value = a1.value.replace(reg, '');
};
```

```html
<input value="lalala;mememe" id="a1">
<input value=";mememe" id="a2">
<button>Заменить</button>
```

*Примечание: id не должен начинаться с цифры*

Comment: Примечание 2: но и с цифрой прокатит :)

Comment: `new RegExp(a2.value, 'i')` - а вот так не надо делать - кто спецсимволы экранировать будет? И вообще, а при чём тут onload? Делать такие вещи в onload - это какой-то бред.

Comment: @Qwertiy, покажите ваше решение :)

Comment: А я вообще суть вопроса не понял)

Comment: @Qwertiy, суть была в том, что бы удалить текст из первого input, который указан во втором

Comment: "Примечание: id не должен начинаться с цифры" - это не так для html5